# Streamlit - Combining st.button with st.experimental_data_editor

Tags: pandas, streamlit

I am working on a Streamlit app that combines st.button and st.experimental_data_editor that. The idea behind is:

- User should be able to add or delete rows using experimental_data_editor;
- When user click button (via st.button), we should add row to st.experimental_data_editor;
- The “recent” added row from click button can be removed by user if desired;
- If user click button twice, two rows should be added to st.experimental_data_editor.

What is not working?

- When I click “Add row to data editor”, the row is added correctly. However, if I click again, my previously added row will go away;
- If I delete a row using st.experimental_data_editor, any “added rows” via button get removed.

Code:

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "col1": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        "col2": [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
        "col3": [100, 200, 300, 400, 500],
    }
)
if "df_value" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.df_value = df

edited_df = st.experimental_data_editor(
    df,
    key="editor", # An optional string or integer to use as the unique key for the widget. 
    num_rows="dynamic",
)

if edited_df is not None and not edited_df.equals(st.session_state["df_value"]):
    # This will only run if
    # 1. Some widget has been changed (including the dataframe editor), triggering a
    # script rerun, and
    # 2. The new dataframe value is different from the old value
    #update(edited_df)
    st.session_state["df_value"] = edited_df


if st.button('Add row to data editor'): #only add when user clicks Add;
    bla = pd.DataFrame({
                                    "col1": [now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")],
                                    "col2": [112321],
                                    "col3": [1001231],
                                })
    edited_df = pd.concat([st.session_state["df_value"],bla])

if edited_df is not None and not edited_df.equals(st.session_state["df_value"]):
    # This will only run if
    # 1. Some widget has been changed (including the dataframe editor), triggering a
    # script rerun, and
    # 2. The new dataframe value is different from the old value
    #update(edited_df)
    st.session_state["df_value"] = edited_df

edited_df = st.experimental_data_editor(
    edited_df,
    key="editor2", # An optional string or integer to use as the unique key for the widget. 
    num_rows="dynamic",
)
```